# Problems Deploying to Linode with Capistrano

Tags: deployment, capistrano, linode

I`m looking for any guidance on deploying to Linode with Capistrano.

Everything seems fine until the point below:

```
[example.com :: out] Password: Password:   ** [example.com :: out]  ** [example.com :: out] HEAD is now at dc70d86 Fixed bugs from Webmaster Tools.
    command finished in 9912ms
    copying the cached version to /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20121024201633   * executing "cp
-RPp /home/deploy/example.com/shared/cached-copy /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20121024201633 && (echo dc70d867e1b01427a776ef23b59ddd375d39a34b > /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20121024201633/REVISION)"
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command  ** [out :: example.com] cp: cannot create directory `/home/deploy/example.com/releases/20121024201633'  ** [out :: example.com] : No such file or directory
    command finished in 661ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back   * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20121024201633; true"
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command
    command finished in 623ms failed: "sh -c 'cp -RPp /home/deploy/example.com/shared/cached-copy /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20121024201633 && (echo dc70d867e1b01427a776ef23b59ddd375d39a34b > /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20121024201633/REVISION)'" on example.com
```

Any clues to why the directory doesn`t get created or what can I do to fix it?

All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some of the directories in this /home/deploy/example.com/releases/ path do not exist.

Try to run `cap deploy:setup` and to make sure also `mkdir -p /home/deploy/example.com/releases` on the servers shell.

Comment: Also might be a good idea after running `cap deploy:setup` to run `cap deploy:cold` on the first run.